# How to pass headers in nginx for websockets?

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I'm trying to proxy pass a websocket with nginx. My nginx.conf looks like this:

```
    server{
    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;

    location /socket.io/ {

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:3000/socket.io/";
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:3000/";
    }
}
```

But the headers are not send and websocket dosn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code at the start of your `default.conf`

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
     default upgrade;
     '' close;
}
```

You can read more on the topic [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/)